# ¿Cómo puedo sustituir valores de una columna a otra de un DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estoy Trabajando con Python, Numpy y Pandas. Tengo un archivo el cual tiene una columnas con unos y ceros, por ejemplo:

```
array=[1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1]
```

El problema es que esto es difícil de leer, en el sentido de que una persona sólo ve 1 y 0. ¿Cómo puedo cambiar esos valores en el DataFrame(o en un array) por algo más legible para el "Humano", es decir, cambiar los números por palabras (0 por "falta", 1 por "presente").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguramente con `numpy` también lo deberías poder resolver, sin embargo esta es una solución usando comprensión de listas:

```
import numpy as np 

df = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1])

new_df = np.array(["Presente" if e == 1 else "Falta" for e in df])
print(new_df)
```

La salida:

```
['Presente', 'Falta', 'Falta', 'Falta', 'Falta', 'Presente', 'Presente', 'Falta', 'Presente', 'Falta', 'Presente', 'Presente', 'Presente', 'Falta', 'Falta', 'Falta', 'Presente']
```

Creamos un nuevo array `numpy`, a partir de una nueva lista basada en el dataframe original cuyos items son `"Presente"` en caso que el elemento sea 1 y `"Falta"` en caso contrario.

Y por último, usando solo numpy

```
new_df = df.astype('str')
new_df[new_df == "1"] = "Presente"
new_df[new_df == "0"] = "Falta"
```

Answer (score 2):

Para contextualizar vamos a inventarnos un DataFrame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = {"Alumnos": ("Ana",  "Pedro",  "Juan",  "Luis",  "Maria"), 
            "Lista": (1, 0, 1, 1, 0)}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df
  Alumnos  Lista
0     Ana      1
1   Pedro      0
2    Juan      1
3    Luis      1
4   Maria      0
```

Podemos usar NumPy como hace Patricio en su respuesta o si asumimos que son valores 0 y 1 `(False` y `True`) podemos usar `numpy.where`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df['Lista'] = np.where(df['Lista'], 'presente', 'falta')
```

No obstante, dado que mencionas explícitamente Pandas, podemos usar el método [`pandas.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) que usa un diccionario donde cada clave es un valor a sustituir y el valor de esa clave es el nuevo valor por el que es substituido:

```
>>> df.replace({'Lista': {1: "presente", 0: "falta"}},  inplace = True)
```

En cualquier caso la salida será:

```
>>> df
  Alumnos     Lista
0     Ana  presente
1   Pedro     falta
2    Juan  presente
3    Luis  presente
4   Maria     falta
```